# Sync AD thumbnailPhoto with all company computers

Tags: active-directory

I'm perfoming some tests with AD related with `thumbnailPhoto` and `jpegPhoto` AD attributes. I uploaded a photo in my AD user in both attributes using [following this blog entry](http://blog.cjwdev.co.uk/2010/11/03/the-thumbnailphoto-attribute-explained/). However, the photo is not automatically updated in computers in the domain.

Is there a missing step to sync these photos with the Windows users?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it doesn't work this way. The Exchange/Outlook/Lync ecosystem is an exception because it will download the `thumbnailPhoto` of other users from AD into the Outlook or Lync applications, but Windows doesn't. There exists no out-of-the-box mechanism that will download the pictures of all users in AD and store the images locally as profile images on each PC. Nor will LogonUI.exe read thumbnailPhotos from the network when you log on to a PC or when you RDP to a remote server.  You can use Group Policy to assign "default" account pictures, but it is not dynamic.

Comment: But it doesn't exist a workaround or something based on GPO to make this work?